# Can I put IF statements in a switch case function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's me again :)
Some helpful members helped me get a script working, but I ran into a brick wall with a case that I also want to have an IF statement. It looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
      switch(this.id) {
        case:'buttonone':
              if( $('#one').attr('readonly')) {

                $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Save');
                $('#one').attr('readonly', false);
                $('#one').addClass('focusField');
                $("#questiononetext").html("When do you want to go out?");

} else {

                $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Change');
                $('#one').attr('readonly', true);
                $('#one').removeClass('focusField');
                $("#questiononetext").html("Date: ");

} break;
        case 'buttontwo': $("#questiononetext").html("Content changed"); break;
        case 'buttonthree': $("#content").html("Content changed again"); break;
      }
    });
});
```

Notice what comes after CASE: buttonone, I tried an if statement and that broke the whole script. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens? Thank you :)))

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you can make use of attributes like `data-key = value`, think it would help you reduce the code and make unecessary the use of a switch.

Comment: Hello yoda, I am unsure what you mean because I am a newbie :) I will, however do a google search to find out. Thanks!

Comment: If you clarify what you pretend to do with that code, It might help for someone to come with a sollution (paste some markup as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is it the extra colon after the "case" in "case: buttonone". Please check

Comment: It WAS the colon. I didn't notice that, thank you Shadow! :)...edit: I can accept your question in 5 minutes, so I will do so when I get back from lunch. Thanks again to you and everyone else who looked over my code, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

Your switch statement is redundant, the only reason it's there is you're using the same `click` handler for multiple buttons, but they share nothing in common.

Instead you should have 3 `click` handlers:

```
$('#buttonone').click(function(){
  ...
});

$('#buttontwo').click(function(){
  ...
});

$('#buttonthree').click(function(){
  ...
});
```

And the `if` statement in buttonone's handler is totally legitimate.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for your answer however I moved away from this function to have a more compact code. If, however you think this is a better solution please let me know and I will use this instead :)

Comment: I think what @Jamiec suggests is more readable and less error prone. If you value compactness over these, then sure, but you're saving only a couple of lines and you're not going to run out of space...

Comment: I agree with Jamie this is a far better solution cause each element would have it's own dedicated handler, and no risk for collision if afterwards you add extra button that would not use this "global" handler.

Comment: @pufAmuf - How is your code "more compact"? You need to introduce a switch statement for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I wasn't saying you are wrong - I would never do that I'm a newbie. This is why I was asking for your opinion which I value. Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I think IF within CASE has no problem. problem may be `$('#one').attr('readonly')`. use can use `data` property here. I test that `$('#one').attr('readonly')` is not working.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, but the problem was with the colon after 'case' :)